# RAID upgrade - Can I power down individual disks to 'hot upgrade' an array?

Tags: raid, storage, hp

I have a 4 disk RAID6 on an HP P420i (w/FBWC + battery module) that I need to upgrade with larger disks.

I was going to replace each disk in turn then wait for array rebuild until all 4 were replaced. Can I power down individual disks in the array (possibly using software like HP Smart Storage) so I can do this while 'hot' or is it safe to just remove a disk from an online array without any preparation? I'd like to avoid turning the machine off at all if it's possible.

Comment: Curious... Why a 4-disk RAID6?

Comment: It was either that or RAID 10 and performance wasn't a huge consideration so better redundancy won out. What RAID level would you choose in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can hot-replace the drives one at a time. Depending on the disk capacity, this will be a long process.

At the end of the rebuilds, available space in the Array will increase. You'll need to increase the Logic Drive size in the Smart Storage Administrator.

Comment: Thanks mate! I was pretty certain it would be fine but wanted to bounce it off someone. Hot swap successful and rebuilding right now :)